# Can't click on browser vertical scrollbar because of a fullscreen fixed bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 on my project, and modified the modal style in order to make it fullscreen like you can see it on this css code:

```
.modal.show  {
  display:flex!important;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  /* background: blue !important; */
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  right: 3%;
  float: none;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.modal-backdrop.modal-backdrop-transparent {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.modal-backdrop.modal-backdrop-transparent.in {
  opacity: .9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

.modal-backdrop.modal-backdrop-fullscreen {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.modal-backdrop.modal-backdrop-fullscreen.in {
  opacity: .97;
  filter: alpha(opacity=97);
}

.modal-fullscreen {
  background: #fff;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.modal-dialog {
  position:fixed;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

When I tried to scroll down the vertical scrollbar of the browser, it won't ! I can use mouse scroll wheel but not by clicking on it directly !

Are you able to detect the problem ? It's for sure the fixed position but it is needed to make it fullscreen.

Here a jsfiddle to see a live demo of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/odbjcpt2/1/

I don't want to use position FLEX instead of FIXED since it won't solve the problem on my project, even if in the example given it will works (modal keep ading padding-right to body ... it is fixed using FIXED).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your JSFiddle, the problem appears to be with the div that contains the Lorem Ipsum text.  It has `pointer-events: auto;` inherited from .modal-content class and if you remove that it ends up with `pointer-events: none;` inherited from modal-dialog class.  If you take both those away, the problem goes away.

*EDIT*

I believe the root of the issue is that you're setting your .modal-dialog class to have fixed position and overflow auto.

Below is from bootstrap doc

> Modals use position: fixed, which can sometimes be a bit particular
>   about its rendering. Whenever possible, place your modal HTML in a
>   top-level position to avoid potential interference from other
>   elements. You’ll likely run into issues when nesting a .modal within
>   another fixed element.

After playing around, if I edit your CSS in your JSFiddle example and in the .modal-dialog class I just remove `position:fixed;` and `overflow:auto;`, the problem goes away.

**EDIT AGAIN**

I just noticed you actually have .modal-dialog defined in your CSS twice, the first time with flex position and second time with fixed.  Sounds like that was maybe a copy/paste mistake.  Anyhow, still the same root cause I think, because your .modal-dialog div is fixed and it's inside your .modal div, and bootstrap doc says don't put another fixed inside a .modal

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your answer ... but unfortunately I can't see the pointer-events on the code I posted ? can you give more infos please ?

Comment: If you go to Dev Tools in your browser you can see all the CSS that's being applied to each DOM element.  So if you're in Chrome for example and you hit F12 to open Dev Tools, then open your modal and right click on the Lorem Ipsum text and select Inspect, it'll show you that DOM element in HTML and it'll show you all the CSS that's applied and which classes it's coming from.  You'll see that on your div that holds your Lorem Ipsum (which is inside a div with modal-body class on it) that there is a pointer-events: auto that is applied from the modal-content class

Comment: Also I'm sorry I don't fully understand why you're seeing this behavior, but all I can say is that if I uncheck pointer-events: auto; on the modal-content class, and then uncheck pointer-events: none; on the modal-dialog class in dev tools, the problem goes away.